# Vector Space Dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A,B$ be $n\times m$, $s\times m$ matrices respectively, and let $$V=\{X\in \mathbb{F}^{m\times n};\ B X A=0\}.$$ Suppose that $$rank(A)=r,\ rank(B)=m.$$ Show that $dim V=m(n-r)$.

I have no idea.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{P}^{m\times n}$?

Comment: Hint: You can calculate dimensions by looking for a basis of the vector space.

Comment: @EuYu $\mathbb{P}$ is just a field, and $\mathbb{P}^{m\times n}$ is then $m\times n$ matrix.

Comment: @XLDD I see, $\mathbb{P}$ is rather non-standard for denoting a field. Would you mind if I changed it to $\mathbb{F}$? Others might wonder about this without looking at the comments.

Comment: @EuYu Great idea.

Comment: @BISHD How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that from rank-nullity, we have
$$m = \mathrm{rank}(B) + \mathrm{nullity}(B) = m + \mathrm{nullity}(B)$$
Therefore $B$ has a trivial nullspace. It follows that if $BXA = 0$ then we have $XA = 0$. This happens if and only if $\mathrm{Im}(A) \subseteq \ker(X)$.

Fix a basis of $\mathrm{Im}(A)$ and extend this to a basis of $\mathbb{F}^n$. With respect to this basis, $X$ satisfies the required condition if and only if the columns corresponding to the vectors in $\mathrm{Im}(A)$ are zero. There are $r$ such columns of $m$ entries each. It follows you are free to vary the remaining $mn - mr = m(n-r)$ entries. Therefore the dimension of the space is $m(n-r)$.